# How to know the write concern associated to a connection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm debugging a piece of software that connects to MongoDB using the write concern as a parameter for the connection. I'm trying to check if that software connects as expected.

Using MongoDB 4.4.1 (with out-of-the-box configuration) when my software connect I see this trace in the log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-25T12:03:39.550+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:46444","connectionId":35207,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-25T12:03:39.551+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn35207","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:46444","client":"conn35207","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongoc","version":"1.17.4"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Debian GNU/Linux","version":"9","architecture":"x86_64"},"platform":"cfg=0x028156a0e9 posix=200809 stdc=201112 CC=GCC 6.3.0 20170516 CFLAGS=\"\" LDFLAGS=\"\""}}}
```

Nothing is told in the logs about the write concern used in that connection.

Is there any way to know the write concern associated to a connection either in the logs or by any other means (e.g. mongo shell)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you would know the Write Concern, it would not help you.

Write Concern can be set on Client/Connection level, on database level, on collection level and on operation/command level. Some commands have a fix Write Concern (e.g. `sh.enableSharding()` uses always `majority`, no matter of any other settings).

I don't see any value of the connection Write Concern, see [Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-defaults/#write-concern)

Comment: Do you mean that trying to get the WC at the MongoDB server is pointless as the WC is at client side? Makes sense...

Comment: Yes, the server just defines some **defaults** but in the end it can be everything for every single command.

Comment: So probably what I need to test my software is to look a the operation information at the server side and see the associated WC used by the client on it. I'll have a look to see how mongo log can print full information for each operation. Thanks for your feedback!